# Definite Integral of derivative gives distance between function at integral limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$ whose derivative exists everywhere for $x\in [a,b]$. Let us denote The derivative of this function with respect to $x$ as $f_x(x,y)$

Then I believe the fundamental theorem of calculus (or perhaps a corollary of it) says that
$$
\int_a^b  f_x(t,y) dt =  f(b,y) - f(a,y)
$$
?

So then the integral of the derivative between two points is just the difference of the function at the two points? (with the second argument held constant at $y$ in this multivariable case)

Comment: The function $x \mapsto f_x(x,y)$ has to be continuous for every $y$ (or at least absolutely integrable if you want this to be true almost everywhere).

Comment: @LL3.14 Why would other values of $y$ matter if I am looking at one specific value of $y$? (Put differently, if I want the integral in my question to be the distance between $b$ and $a$ *for any $y$* then I can see why I would need it to be continuous for every $y$, but if I just want to be sure that it is the distance between $b$ and $a$ *for that specific value, $y$* then why would it need to be continuous for every $y$?) (sorry about some abuse of notation with $y$)

Comment: Oh yes of course if you need only one value of $y$ then one value of $y$ is sufficient

Comment: For Riemann integral you need the existence of the integral as a part of hypotheses and then your result is true.

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Corolary you have enounced is known as Barrow's Rule. So, the answer to your question is "yes".

If you have a multivariable function but you are helding constant all of the variables but one, it is like having an funciton from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.